# Delete a wiki page with powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need help with my code.
I first tried to create a new wiki page in SharePoint 2013 and that worked perfectly.
Now I'm trying to delete a wiki page and that doesn't work very well.

My code:

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Users\Benutzername\AppData\Local\Apps\OfficeDevPnP.PowerShell.V15.Commands\Modules\OfficeDevPnP.PowerShell.V15.Commands\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type –Path "C:\Users\Benutzername\AppData\Local\Apps\OfficeDevPnP.PowerShell.V15.Commands\Modules\OfficeDevPnP.PowerShell.V15.Commands\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

Function Delete-WikiPage ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [string]$WikiLibraryTitle,[string]$PageName)
{
    $wikiLibrary = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($wikiLibraryTitle)
    $context.Load($wikiLibrary.RootFolder.Files)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $wikiPage = $wikiLibrary.RootFolder.Files | Where {$_.Name -eq $pageName}
    $context.Load($wikiPage)
    $context.DeleteObject()
}
$Url = "hhtps://sharepoint.com"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$pageName = "Testlauf.aspx"
Delete-WikiPage -Context $context -WikiLibraryTitle "Testwiki" -PageName $pageName
```

I got an error message about the DeleteObject() method but I didn't find anything how I can fix that:

```
Error when calling the method [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext] no method found with the name "DeleteObject".
In C:\Users\Benutzername\Desktop\Projektarbeit_Wiki\PowerShell\Delete_WikiPage.ps1:12 Zeichen:5
+     $context.DeleteObject()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I can only work with methods from the Add-Types. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The [`ClientContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext_members.aspx) class doesn't have `DeleteObject()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the CSOM in PowerShell. (you load the CSOM DLL ).
So you should search information with SharPoint CSOM.

To answer you question, you use : **DeleteObject()** on you object : **context**. This methode doesn't exist on the Context Object. But the methode exist on the File.

Si you should try something like :

```
$wikiPage = $wikiLibrary.RootFolder.Files | Where {$_.Name -eq $pageName}
$context.Load($wikiPage)
$context.ExecuteQuery() //Get the item, but not sure this is needed
$wikiPage.DeleteObject()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

personal Note : 
You should use CAML query to retrieve your WikiPage, not this: $wikiPage = $wikiLibrary.RootFolder.Files | Where {$_.Name -eq $pageName}
With this kind of query you have bad performance, and you can raise exception list threshold

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution I needed! :D